# Units of android EXTRA_SCALE and LEVEL in battery manager

Tags: android, batterymanager

At the beginning I thought that EXTRA_LEVEL would return a percentage but I've seen in the API that to get the percentage I have to do EXTRA_LEVEL / EXTRA_SCALE

So now, I wonder, in which units are those pararameters? Are they mA?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is about the battery level? Please make it more clear in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXTRA_SCALE` value is (almost?) always set to 100. `EXTRA_LEVEL` does not contain a value in mA but the level from 0 to `EXTRA_SCALE`. Thus, assuming that `EXTRA_SCALE` is always 100, `EXTRA_LEVEL` would in fact contain the percentage. However, by computing the division you get the relative battery level as a fraction even if `EXTRA_SCALE` had a different value than 100.

Comment: In which cases EXTRA_SCALE may not be 100?

Comment: I'm not aware of any but since there's nowhere a contract/guarantee that EXTRA_SCALE always is 100 you should use the method shown in the official documentation.